# Hölder-Zygmund spaces of negative order

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, besov-spaces

In the equation (1.1.17) in Proposition 1.1.6 (ii) in Alazard and Delort's *Sobolev Estimates for Two Dimensional Water Waves*, there appears a norm named $C^{-1}$, but in Chapter 6 (Appendix) of the same book I can only find the definition of $C^s$ for $s\ge0$. Though in that particular proposition I can sort of figure out what $C^{-1}$ really means (it is actually the Besov space $B^{-1}_{\infty,\infty}$,) but I am wondering **if there is a universally recognized definition of  Hölder-Zygmund spaces of negative order**, better backed up by some references.

Comment: This seems just like a choice of notation by the authors. My understanding is that the Zygmund class of spaces $C^{s}$ was introduced to extend the scale of Holder spaces to integer values while still preserving certain boundedness properties of Calderon-Zygmund operators. These boundedness properties may fail if the integer endpoint space is taken to be the Lipschitz spaces. The preceding makes sense for nonnegative values of $s$. The Besov scale $B_{\infty,\infty}^{s}$ recovers the Holder-Zygmund spaces $C^{s}$ for nonnegative $s$, but also extends the scale to negative values of $s$.